# How to know the max number of characters that will fit on a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I don't know how to do this.
I did a script, that can write in a `div` box. But, the problem is that, I need the number of characters I could write in a line of a `div`.

For example: 
If I have a box 20*20, and I can write 15 characters per line, how can I get this 15 number? With tried `.length` but I couldn't do this.

Comment: This number will depends on characters entered. You should rather tell us what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Characters come in all shapes and sizes. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rajesh For example, If you write "hello hello hello hello hello" my script split the text where you want and write "read more". I need the max lenght, because I want to split the text where is the end of the line.

Comment: @squint For example, If you write "hello hello hello hello hello" my script split the text where you want and write "read more". I need the max lenght, because I want to split the text where is the end of the line.

Comment: If you search, you'll find was to accomplish this that don't involve counting characters.

Comment: @srpitilitano Point was if you add `.` after every hello, number of characters will vary. You can still look into `overflow` css property.